# need to create macro in Slick-C to re-enumerate

Tags: slickedit

I have a bunch of test cases in an XML file named : blah_blah_blah_blah_number

The test cases have the numbers all messed up like:

```
blah_3
blah_1
blah_7
....
```

I need to re-number them. So that the first one gets renumbered 1, the second 2.. and so on. I want to build a macro for this but I don't know how to start. I need some sort of search function that can go to the pattern I give it, and then it substitutes the number with a count that I keep in some variable. I'm not proficient at all with Slick-C, and would like to get this done quickly :\

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Comment: Not following, are these in XML file, file loaded as a buffer?  [not that I have a pending answer, I know some slickc, but not xml manipulation in slick-c]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more timely answer, you might consider the SlickEdit forums on slickedit.com, but I'll try here.
I would load the file in a buffer, and create a macro along the following lines:

- Create a while loop incrementing a counter
- In the while loop, use `search` with regular expressions to find the next occurrence
- When the next occurrence is found, use `search_replace` to replace the string found with a new string composed using the counter variable, and to repeat the previous search
- When nothing is to be found any more, terminate the loop

Without testing it on an XML file, this should give you a start for your function (assuming you know how to create a macro file and load it into SE), a quick test showed it to work on a plain text file, no guarantees, however:

```
/* Demo for StackOverflow question 14205293 */
_command my_renumber() name_info(','VSARG2_MARK|VSARG2_REQUIRES_EDITORCTL)
{
  int not_found = 0; /* boolean to terminate loop */
  int iLoop = 0;     /* Counter to renumber items */

  /* Use search initially; if that call doen't find an item, we're done. */
  if (search('blah_:i', 'R') != 0)
  {
    not_found = 1;
  }

  while (!not_found)
  {
    if (search_replace('blah_' :+ iLoop, 'R') == STRING_NOT_FOUND_RC)
    {
      not_found = 1;
    }
    iLoop++;
  }
}
```